# Three.js does not output plane

Tags: three.js

Three.js does not render a plane and only outputs a black screen.

Here is my code:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script src="three.js"></script>
<script>
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById('myCanvas'), antialias: true});
renderer.setClearColor(0x00ff00);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60,40,1,1);
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry,planeMaterial);

scene.add(plane);
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
scene.add(ambientLight);

var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );

scene.add( spotLight );

requestAnimationFrame(render);

    function render() {
        mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }


</script>
```

Please could anybody help.Why is the plane not being displayed. Am I using a wrong three.js library or is the code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Move the camera along the Z axis by 5.

So:

```
camera.postion.z += 1;
```